# How to fix this Script for the correct output?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, if-statement

I am trying to compare actual values from `/etc/sysctl.conf` to the recommended values using shell scripting. Both the values are same but instead of `if`, `else` statement is getting executing.

```sh
shmmnireq=4096
shmmni=$(grep "shmmni" /etc/sysctl.conf | cut -d " " -f3)
echo $shmmnireq
echo $shmmni
if [[ $shmmnireq  == $shmmni ]];then
    echo "shmmni is configured"
else
    echo "shmmni is not configured"
fi
```

**Output:**

```
4096
4096
shmmni is not configured
```

Comment: Try [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net/)

Comment: Remove blank lines from your code, select your code with mouse, click on the ``{}` tool on the edit menu,.Now code is properly formatted. ++for shellcheck.net . Good luck.

Comment: If statement should have one ‘=‘ instead of ‘==‘. Numeric comparison ‘-eq’

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
#!/bin/bash
shmmnireq=4096
shmmni=$(grep "shmmni" /etc/sysctl.conf | cut -d " " -f3)    
echo $shmmnireq
echo $shmmni
if [ "$shmmnireq" -eq "$shmmni" ];then
    echo "shmmni is configured"
else
    echo "shmmni is not configured"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tested below code. This will work:

```
#!/bin/bash

shmmnireq=4096
shmmni=$(grep "shmmni" /etc/sysctl.conf | cut -d " " -f3)
echo $shmmnireq
echo $shmmni
if [[ ${shmmnireq}  -eq ${shmmni} ]]
then
    echo "shmmni is configured"
else
    echo "shmmni is not configured"
fi
```